# Talking to oneself

Tags: sentence-choice

Suppose that someone wants to do something for someone. I am drinking tea. I think I should give a cup of tea to my brother too. What is the better way to say this, while I'm thinking to do this or asking myself to this.

> 1. Let me get my bro a cup of tea.
> 2. Why don't I make my bro a cup of tea.

Comment: "Better" in what way? Both of your examples are grammatically correct (assuming you put a question mark on the second one). There are also a lot of other ways you could say this: "I think I'll get some tea for my brother, too." "I should get him a cup of tea also." "Maybe my bro would also like some tea?" etc. Which one you use depends on context and personal preference. So please explain what you mean when you ask which is "better".

Comment: I meant which one is grammatically better? Situation: I'm taking tea. Now it occurs to me that I should give my bro a cup of tea too.

Comment: The second one is a question, so should have a question mark. Other than that, both of them are grammatically fine. It would be more about your mood: "Let me get my bro a cup of tea" is a statement. You are telling yourself and/or everyone else that this is what is going to happen. "Why don't I make my bro a cup of tea?" is less certain. You are asking yourself/everyone else if you should do this.

Comment: There's something odd about this question from an English Learning point of view...  People learn English to communicate with people who don't know their native tongue, but do know English.  But when thinking to yourself, why would you use English, or at least why would you worry if it is correct or not?  Could this be for a piece of fiction writing?

Comment: Yes. Actually I write.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking to oneself, any of these alternatives should work:

- "I should make him a cup of tea also."
- "I'm going to make him a cup of tea also."
- "Why don't I make him a cup of tea." (a rhetorical question)
- "Let's make him a cup of tea, shall we?"  (the "[royal we](https://grammarist.com/usage/royal-we/)" is comical)
- "I think I'll get some tea for my brother, too."

Regarding this option you mentioned:

- "Let me get my bro a cup of tea."

At least to me, this sounds like something you would say *out loud*, to tell others in the room what you're doing. But that doesn't rule it out, if it's what pops into your mind.